# Derivation of decay rate formula

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I'm having difficulty understanding the formula of decay rate. I have read a few other sources but it raises more questions as I was trying to follow their derivation. So, here I present the method from my lecture notes.

To derive the decay rate formula, we have the transition rate per unit volume:
$$
w_{fi} = (2\pi)^4 \delta^{(4)}(P_f - P_i) |M|^2,
$$
where $P_i,\;P_f$ are the total 4-momentum of initial-, final-state particles respectively, and $M$ the Feynman amplitude.

Also, we obtain the *density of final states*
$$
\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^32\omega(\vec{p})} 
$$
from the completeness relation. Also, a density of $2\omega(\vec{p})$ particles per unit volume is obtained from the normalization of one-particle state.

The decay rate for a single particle decaying into $n$ particles is given by:
$$
d\Gamma = (2\pi)^4 \delta^{(4)}( p - \sum p_f ) \frac{1}{2\omega(\vec{p})} \prod_f \frac{d^3 p_f}{(2\pi)^2 2E_f} |M|^2:= \frac{1}{2E(\vec{p})}|M|^2 (dPS)_n,
$$
where $(dPS)_n = (2\pi)^4 \delta^{(4)}( p - \sum p_f )\prod_f \frac{d^3 p_f}{(2\pi)^2 2E_f} $ is the n-particle phase space.

As the decay rate is the transition rate per decaying particle, I assume the factor of $\frac{1}{2\omega(\vec{p})}$ is to reduce the transition rate per unit volume $w_{fi}$ to transition rate per particle. But how do we interpret the production of densities of final states?

Also, there would be a product of $n$ final state densities, would be dimension analysis be satisfied? And what's the physical meaning of the n-particle phase state $(dPS)_n$?

Comment: Which book are you reading?

Comment: @schris38 The method I'm presenting here is from the QFT lecture notes from my school.